# Maxima -- Reduction of Logical expressions

Tags: logical-operators, symbolic-math, maxima

Consider the following sequences of maxima's instructions:

```
(in1) x=0;
(out) x=0

(in2) y>0;
(out) y>0

(in3) x>0 and y>0;
(out) x>0 and y>0

(in4) x=0 or y>0;
(out) y>0

(in5) x=0 and y>0;
(out) false
```

The first three instructions produce expected outputs.
however, why does the logical proposition "x=0" in the inputs (in4) and (in5) are considered to be equal to false ?

We can see that when the expression "x=0" is isolated, it doesn't give a specific value (here false) to it, I don't understand these outputs conceptually and mathematically, it is not the mathematical behavior expected..

Here are some strange behavior when I try to debug.

```
(in1) prederror:true$
(in2) debugmode(true)$
(in3) x=0;
(out) x=0
(in4) y>0;
(out) y>0
(in5) x=0 or y>0;
(out) Unable to evaluate predicate y > 0
```

What does it mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here?

```
x > 0 and y > 0;
```

Arguments `[x > 0]` and `[y > 0]` are evaluated to themself. `[[x > 0]
and [y > 0]]` is also evaluated to itself.

```
x = 0 or y > 0;
```

`[x = 0]` is evaluated to `false` and `[y > 0]` is evaluated to itself, `[false
or [y > 0]]` is evaluated to `[y > 0]`.

```
x = 0 and y > 0;
```

`[x = 0]` is evaluated to `false` and `[false and [y > 0]]` is immediately
evaluted to `false` without evaluting a second argument.

Relevent sections of documentation are

- [evalution](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_8.html#SEC44)
- [and](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_7.html#IDX231)
- [=](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_7.html#IDX231)
- [equal](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_11.html#IDX434)